# How to run Google Chrome in a single process?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, process

Is it possible to run Google Chrome in a single process?

I found the only flag – `--single-process` – but running Chrome with it shows me the following message:

> *You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --single-process. Stability and security will suffer.*

and it still runs in multiple processes...

Is there something similar?

Comment: That flag was removed a long time ago and no longer works.

Comment: I've already understood that :). Is there something similar?

Comment: Not with Chrome, as far as I know. You could check if `Chromium` still supports the flag.

Comment: I remember Chrome had some sort of option in it's preferences, but as I don't use the browser I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Would you please explain why you want to run the browser as a single process?

Comment: Is it because of something like this: http://futureoptimistnow.blogspot.in/2012/12/single-process-mode-in-chrome.html ?

Comment: Presumably to reduce the ridiculous RAM usage.  An Opera heavy-research session with 50+ tabs has less RAM usage than my typical chrome session.

Comment: Tried --process-per-site, and it's no longer working as well.

Comment: **Chromium** seems to still work with `--single-process` but does give a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The `--single-process` option you've found is [not officially supported](https://crbug.com/1162815#c5), so it's not guaranteed to work, may still use [more than a single process](https://superuser.com/q/952302/1270846#comment2497809_1623567) and may cause [additional performance or stability issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20220125002107/https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models/#TOC-Single-process).

There are a couple of other Chromium options you could use instead:

1. Since Chromium 67 you may want to disable [Site Isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation/) using flag `chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out` or `--disable-site-isolation-trials` command line option. This will force subframes to run in their pages' processes and allow you to use the next option;
2. You could explicitly limit the amount of renderer processes using `--renderer-process-limit=2` [command line option](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#renderer-process-limit). This will force all the tabs and extensions to use a single process (per each type);
3. With `--in-process-gpu` option it will [run the GPU process as a thread in the main browser process](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#in-process-gpu). These processes consume most of the CPU time and the GPU driver crash will likely crash the whole browser, so you probably don't wanna use it.

> **Warning!**
> Most of these options will reduce the security of your browser! You use them at your own risk.

---

I was testing these options on Vivaldi 3.3 (Chrome 85) with 5 Super User tabs, 3 other tabs and 4 extensions. Here are the results I've got:

```
Default:                                    24 processes
Default - Site Isolation:                   19 processes
Default - Site Isolation + Renderer Limit:  10 processes
```